# Can this question be reworded so as to be reopened?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I was looking for online retailers that specialize in RPGs, and I came across [this closed question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2782/where-can-i-buy-original-edition-and-out-of-print-roleplaying-books-and-accessor). The question was not my exact one (I explicitly did not want eBay as an answer, for example), but close enough that it would have likely been listed as a duplicate.

I would like to know if there is some way to retool the question so it can be reopened, and if so, how would I go about doing so?

Comment: I couldn't think of a way for it to work.

Comment: Neither can I. It's a giant list question and varies hugely. Some questions we're simply not very good at.

Comment: Okay, that's fair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a list question, which we close fast and liberally. In fact, it says so right in the question: *"Let's make a list of them!"*

I'm not sure if there was ever a definitive blog post explaining why list questions are so bad for our format, but at the very least, they violate the [Questions not to ask](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) guideline of every answer being equally valid - people will generally just upvote their favourites, and there's no correct answer.

Leave that question closed. There's nothing needing rescuing in it, it's just not a suitable question.

If you want something similar, you could ask your own question. However... [shopping questions can be problematic](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) and very often get closed. For instance, see this closed shopping queston and its comments: [Where can I buy a massive d4?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/12539/1204).

I recommend you talk to us in chat about exactly what you're after. We may help you work out a question, but it might just be something you need to google. Alternately, someone in chat might already know a place. Chat is often a good place to ask people for help with problems that won't really fit in the site's format, since it's a place we can actually discuss stuff with you.

Answer (score 4):

FYI, there are canonical links on the SE blog, though you'd probably have to hang out for weeks on Meta.SO to find them.

The first is here: [Real questions have answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)

The second is here: [Q&A is hard, let's go shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

The not-as-related third is here: [Good subjective, bad subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). This is the precursor to the other two, and started the scope-limiting that we see today on all SE sites.

Now, it's worth noting that these were originally created for Stack Overflow, where the questions they ask have one singular correct answer. The very nature of RPG.SE means people have different opinions and solutions - the difference is, the question must have an answer. Not necessarily a unique answer, but it must be answerable.

Comment: We also add that they must have a criteria for selecting a correct answer besides "I like it".